# WSDL processing through Apex

Tags: wsdl2apex

I want to parse my WSDL in Apex. I have gone through the options available through Apex Class->Parse WSDL. But issue is that, it has a limitation of choosing a WSDL file of upto 1 MB whereas my WSDL is of more than 2 MB. So, I decided to develop my own parser to parse the WSDL. Looking for the Apex API/method which is actually used in background of that "parse WSDL" button so that i can call that through my code.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are trying to generate Apex classes based on a WSDL, but you've run into limits with the native tool because of file size? Take a look at the [FuseIT SFDC Explorer](http://www.fuseit.com/en/Solutions/SFDC-Explorer/Help-WSDL-Parser.aspx). It allows you generate Apex from WSDL and solves some of the problems with the Salesforce provided tool.